# How to access the $cookies service from within an AngularJS directive definition

Tags: cookies, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have something like the following:

```
angular.module("thingy", ["ngCookies"]).directive("welcome", function() {
    return {
        link: function($scope, el, attr, ctrl) {
                        (if $cookies.something) {
                            // conditional cookie logic
                        }
        },
        templateUrl: "assets/html/_welcome.html"
    };
})
```

How can I read or write to cookies from within that link function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to inject it.  See [this](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di#inlineannotation) documentation.

```
angular.module("thingy", ["ngCookies"]).directive("welcome", ['$cookies', function($cookies) {
  return {
    link: function($scope, el, attr, ctrl) {
      if ($cookies.something) {
        // conditional cookie logic
      }
    },
    templateUrl: "assets/html/_welcome.html"
  };
}])
```

Comment: Yep. Turns out my downfall was forgetting to actually do the injection by passing a $cookies argument to the anonymous function. D'oh!